# Properly handling HighDPI on MacOS with SDL and OpenGL

Tags: macos, opengl, sdl, highdpi

My attempts at High-DPI rendering on MacOS for my game, [Bitfighter](http://bitfighter.org), always end up looking bad, like a scaled-up version of a low-res game.

The game uses SDL2 + OpenGL and I have correctly enabled the `SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI` window flag as well as making it HighDPI aware in the Info.plist.  This all works and I get the higher-res title bar just fine.  I use `SDL_GL_GetDrawableSize` and it correctly returns the 2x larger pixel size than the window size, but the following techniques to re-scale it don't yield good results:

- Using `glViewport` using window coords
- Using `glViewport` with drawable coords, then `glOrtho` to scale (as suggested in the SDL doc `README-ios.md`)

Both show pixely vector graphics.  What can I do to get OpenGL to draw better with MacOS High-DPI?

Thanks.